# Issue with c/c++ build and debugging on vscode

Tags: c, visual-c++

Any time I run a code using c/c++ on my vscode it returns a (The preLaunchTask ‘C/C++: Gcl.exe build active file’ terminated with exit code -1
Also watched some videos on YouTube but they didn't help me
I tried resetting from launch.json but all to no avail

Comment: and you are not using visual studio (not code) because ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error: "The preLaunchTask 'C/C++: g++.exe build active file' terminated with exit code 1"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64519454/error-the-prelaunchtask-c-c-g-exe-build-active-file-terminated-with-exi)